# Reusing randomly generated variables like name in email

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script

How to reuse in Postman variable's value in different variable. For example:

I've made three variables in new **environment** (which is selected as using):

- name, with initial and current value: {{$randomFirstName}}
- surname, with initial and current value: {{$randomLastName}}
- email, with initial and current value: {{name}}{{surname}}@example.com

And in my request JSON I've set:

```
{
    "name": "{{name}}",
    "surname": "{{surname}}",
    "email": "{{email}}"
}
```

But the email consists different name and surname.

```
{
    "name": "Bettye",
    "surname": "Schinner",
    "email": "EthaBotsford@example.loc"
}
```

Then, I've tried to create some **Pre-request sctiprs**. I've cleaned mentioned variables from values.

```
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("name", pm.variables.replaceIn('{{$randomFirstName}}'));
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("surname", pm.variables.replaceIn('{{$randomLastName}}'));
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("email", pm.collectionVariables.get("name")+pm.collectionVariables.get("surname")+"@example.com");
```

But this way I got still same email, independently from name and surname. What do I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I should use **pm.enviornment** instead **pm.collectionVariables**:

```
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("name", pm.variables.replaceIn('{{$randomFirstName}}'));
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("surname", pm.variables.replaceIn('{{$randomLastName}}'));
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("email", pm.environment.get("name")+pm.environment.get("surname")+"@example.test");
```